# Error: googleapi: Error 400: Composer API Service Agent service account

Tags: google-cloud-composer

Error: googleapi: Error 400: Composer API Service Agent service account (service-project#@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com) does not have required permissions set. Cloud Composer API Service Agent role is missing. Please bind roles/composer.serviceAgent back on service-project#

I am deploying composer cluster. Both roles "roles/composer.serviceAgent" and "roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext" were given. Maybe you guys had better luck with this error ?

Comment: Have you tried following the other steps indicated in this https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-environment-creation#insufficient_permissions_to_create_an_environment documentation?

Comment: As mentioned by Scott B, did you follow the steps he shared with you?